# Which Ruby ORM is better or ideal to use?

Tags: mysql, ruby, orm

I am very very very new to Ruby like only 2 days studying the language and while starting my journey, I ended up deciding to create a training application.

Since I need a database with the app I had in mind, I stumbled upon on integrating Ruby with Mysql and that's how I found mysql2 gem. However, I am also curious with what Ruby ORM Framework is good to use or start with. I googled and found these ORM Frameworks: **Active Record, DataMapper, Sequel**

However I didn't understand very well the advantage of using one from another. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. It will be hard to get an answer as it may depend on what you are trying to do, and again, depend on the opinion of the answerers.

Comment: DataMapper is not being actively maintained  (a DataMapper 2, now called Ruby Object Mapper, split from original project my appear some time in the future), so is only of interest if you expect to inherit work on a project already using DataMapper. Either of the other 2 would be fine to start with, and no major advantage/disadvantage for a beginner.

Comment: I see what you mean on opinion base. @neil thanks for the info probably ill go with active record as it more used by rubyist than sequel as i can see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mysql2` gem is only intended for those writing things like ActiveRecord, DataMapper or Sequel to use, so **do not** use it directly. It's a low-level driver.

If you're using Rails, use ActiveRecord. If you want something that's organized, follows strong conventions, and don't require a lot of low-level access to the database, use ActiveRecord. It's a great place to start, and a safe default choice.

If you want something with more flexibility, use Sequel. It's relatively tricky to use since it doesn't have the same simple packaging as ActiveRecord, but can be helpful for those that want a much thinner layer between themselves and the database. It has a very good query composer and an optional model layer, where ActiveRecord is primarily about models.

DataMapper is pretty much defunct and not worth considering. Their newest version only supports Rails 3.1.

Comment: Thanks for this tips. But one more thing, is active record tightly coupled for rails use only?

Comment: @AldeeMativo ActiveRecord has a lot more baggage than Sequel, it depends on things like ActiveSupport, but it's not tightly coupled in any way. You can use it in a Sinatra project, for example, or even a command-line tool. Sequel is generally quicker to load and easy to get started with, but can be more work when your models get very complicated. Trade-offs as always.

Comment: Cool. Sounds promising to dig deeper on these items. Thanks for the hint @tadman. Helps me narrow down some stuffs. :)